# How to Pass Button ID to New Page in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I'm trying to do something that is probably quite simple but I just can't crack it.

In the Ionic 2 framework I want to pass a button ID in a list to a new page using navCtrl.push so that the button clicked will be the title of the page I push to.

My HTML is this:

```
    <ion-item-group>
      <ion-item-divider color="light">B</ion-item-divider>
        <button (click)="dealPage1($event, button)" #button id="Bier 
         Markt" class="button" ion-item >Bier Markt 
          <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="https://s3-
             media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/SaoAO5b2w35dyG460PGc7Q/ls.jpg">
          </ion-avatar>
        </button>
    </ion-item-group>
```

and my TS is this:

```
dealPage1(event, button) {

let data = {
  pagetitle: 'Bier Markt',
  id: button.id,
  title: 'Drinks for Two',
  subtitle: 'By One Cocktail, Get One Free',
  image: 'http://notable.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/canada-day-cocktails.jpg'
};

this.navCtrl.push(DealPage, data);
console.log(button.id);}
```

Currently on my deal page all strings are being passed no problem but the ID is being passed as the number 8, not the string I need "Bier Markt". I've been trying to get this to work for the last few hours on and off but I can't figure it out.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You changed button element to ionic component by applying ion-item attribute.

We are getting [Item](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item.ts) ref so we need to find our button.

try with `button._elementRef.nativeElement.id` line to pass an id.

Comment: Thank you! This 100% got the data flowing, but it lead me to another problem. When I repeat the above structure for multiple items (a list of buttons basically) it will only pass the id for the last item on the list.

So for example if i have #button id="1", #button id="2", #button id="3", etc. All buttons clicked have "3" as the id passed. It seems the id is always set to the final list item.